# Images are not displaying in MonoTouch debug|iphone mode

Tags: iphone, debugging, xamarin.ios

I'm developing app using MonoTouch. In debug|simulator everything looks fine, But when i use debug|iphone images are not displaying.

But when i create test app using (Tabbed Application) template, image are displaying fine.

I have set the build action to "Content" for all images. Am i missing something else?

Comment: the most likely issue is a problem with casing in your paths.  I believe the simulator is more forgiving about this, while the actual device is not.  Be sure your actual file paths/names match what you are using to reference them in code.

Comment: As far as I know, MacOS uses a non-case-sensitive Filesystem and iOS an case-sensitive one. So be sure to have no typos in your filename-references etc.

Comment: @chiffre You are right. The issue with case-sensitive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, MacOS uses a non-case-sensitive Filesystem and iOS an case-sensitive one. So be sure to have no typos in your filename-references etc

//Just added this as an answer, so you can "accept" it :)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a permissions issue on the files, right click one of the files in 
Finder > Get Info, then under Sharing and Permissions make sure everyone has Read Only. I'm betting its currently set to "No Access".

I've seen this a lot when importing files from a Network location.

Andy